# Show a Running Target Based on Today

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting, google-sheets-dates

I'm creating a running target from a quarterly Total divided by known trading days

Current formula in I4 is `=IF(H3<>"",I3+O$30,"")`

H3 = Yesterday's Sales Numbers
I3 = Yesterdays Running Target
O30 = Required Daily Run Rate

Column C is a Date Column

I want the running target to show in I4 when it is Today (currently it shows a day in advance, so showing today the 2-Feb)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- alternative aproach:

  ```
  =IF(AND(C4 < TODAY()+1, H3<>""), I3+O$30, )
  ```

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

- not sure how your dates are generated but one way would be to use conditional formatting and setting font color and cell background to white:

  [image]

Comment: Won't that just take an amount of 1 of the Required Run Rate?

Comment: Have added an image for you now. In short, trying to get the data in column I not to show until that day arrives (currently 3-Feb where I am and data already showing for 4-Feb)

Comment: To give you some context around the dates, I have done a year in advance and use NETWORKDAYS.INTL to calculate the actual trading day per location. I just need to stop the next days Run Rate showing (as it adds to my current week count and wrecks the %). So the data in Column I doesn't need to show until there is data in Column D - Column H

Answer (score 0):

- generating a column of dates with a formula:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(TO_DATE(ROW(INDIRECT("A"&DATE(2019,2,1)):
                            INDIRECT("A"&TODAY()))))
  ```

  [image]
- then you can do:

  ```
  =IF(AND(C4<>"", H3<>""), I3+O$30, )
  ```

  [image]

Answer (score -1):

Solved using the following formula:

```
=IF(AND(C4 < TODAY()+1, H3<>""), I3+O$30, )
```